# React SpringBoot Keycloak No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm aware that this question has been posted several times in this or atleast some same-looking way.
But after try-and-error for the last 6 hours without any luck I had to create another. None of the answers I found solved my problem.

Setup:

- Local keycloak inside docker container on port 8180
- Local web frontend on port 3000
- Local spring backend on port 8080

Flow:
Open web frontend => login using keycloak => request data from backend

Error:
When requesting data from backend CORS error gets fired (Only in browser, no error in spring or keycloak logs)

application.properties:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.realm=Brandsky
keycloak.resource=Brandsky-React
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.cors=true
keycloak.cors-max-age=0
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.cors-allowed-methods=POST, PUT, DELETE, GET
keycloak.cors-allowed-headers=X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000", "http://192.168.178.40:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/admin", "/api/admin/**").hasRole(ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/admin", "/api/admin/**").hasRole(ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/admin", "/api/admin/**").hasRole(ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api", "/api/**").hasAnyRole(USER, ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api", "/api/**").hasAnyRole(USER, ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api", "/api/**").hasAnyRole(USER, ADMIN)
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Example of an endpoint:

```
@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/me")
    public ResponseEntity<?> me(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
}
```

Keycloak Realm Client config (as you see I even tried every combination of redirect uri..):

[image: keycloak conf]

which all then results (as soon as I try to contact the backend)

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/Brandsky/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=Brandsky-React&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.178.40%3A8080%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=de0d62dd-3437-421c-a6ea-8cf26a2c9b3f&login=true&scope=openid' (redirected from 'http://192.168.178.40:8080/api/auth/me/') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?